# Remove "Language Undefined" from content with Multilingual module

Tags: i18n-l10n

Using Multilingual - Internationalization module, now all my pages show:

> Language
>   Undefined

At the bottem. How do I remove this text? I'm using the language switcher, and I have already disabled "Hide content translation links" in the module, but I guess that isn't it.

Comment: What is the link to the project page for the module you report to be using?

Answer (score 5):

You can remove it from : admin - structure - content types - Article / Basic page "Manage Display" - set the language field from "visibe" to "hidden" - Save

Done!